# catching exception objects by reference, temporaries, lifetime issues

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

void foo()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("How long do I live?");
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Why can I catch the exception by reference, isn't `std::runtime_error("How long do I live?")` an rvalue?

How come the exception object is still alive in the catch block?

Where exactly are thrown exception objects stored? What is their lifetime?

Answer (score 7):

In the C++ standard, paragraph 15.1.4:

> The memory for the temporary copy of
>   the exception being thrown is
>   allocated in an unspecified way,
>   except as noted in 3.7.3.1. **The
>   temporary persists as long as there is
>   a handler being executed for that
>   exception**. In particular, if a
>   handler exits by executing a throw;
>   statement, that passes control to
>   another handler for the same
>   exception, so the temporary remains.
>   When the last handler being executed
>   for the exception exits by any means
>   other than throw; the temporary object
>   is destroyed and the implementation
>   may deallocate the memory for the
>   temporary object; any such
>   deallocation is done in an unspecified
>   way. The destruction occurs
>   immediately after the destruction of
>   the object declared in the
>   exception-declaration in the handler.

Note that, in C++-standard talk, a handler denote a `catch` block with the correct argument type.

Comment: The bold text does not refer to the temporary object created in the throw expression. The important fact is that the exception throwing mechanism makes a copy of that temporary in some private area, and then keeps the copy alive. The private copy is what catch handlers receive.

Answer (score 5):

A thrown exception is not a temporary - the compiler-generated exception code keeps a permanent copy of it. So you can bind it to a non-const reference.

[edit]
I just check the standard and it actually refers to a temporary copy. However, the lifetime of the temporary is guaranteed to be at least as long as that of the exception handler.

Answer (score 2):

As Neil said, there is internal compiler magic going on. Also, be aware that the compiler is allowed to create [any number of copies](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.11) of the exception object.

Answer (score 1):

Kudos for trying to understand the details of the language.  At the same time, IMHO, it is far more important to understand why you *should* catch an exception by reference (and throw it by value), than why you *can*.

People typically use a hierarchy of exception classes, and catching by reference allows you to leverage polymorphism, and catch an exception of the base class, when there is no need to handle individual exception types separately.  If you couldn't catch by reference, you would have had to write a `catch` clause for every possible type of exception that can be thrown in the `try` clause.